# How to compare float variable in django template?

Tags: python, django-templates, django-1.11

Attendances is a list of float variables. Even when the value is less than 75, the first case is executed. I know that by default the django template see's a variable as a string. I know how to convert the variable to integer by making it {% attendance|add:0 %}, but what do I do when the values are float?

```
{%for attendance in attendances  %}

                                {%if attendance >= 75 %}
                                    <td><p  style="color:green;">{{attendance}}</p></td>

                                {%else%}
                                    <td><p  style="color:red;">{{attendance}}</p></td>
                                {%endif%}

                      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to construct your own template tag. You can learn how to [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Bellow you may find an example of custom tag for random number in range

```
import random
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def random_int(a, b=None):
    if b is None:
        a, b = 0, a
    return random.randint(a, b)
```

The you can use in your template as follows

```
{% load random_numbers %}

<p>A random value, 1 ≤ {% random_int 1 10 %} ≤ 10.</p>
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you
I created a function to_float in the template tag.

`from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.filter()
def to_float(attendance):
return float(attendance)`